# How to autocomplete taxo term (inside a paragraph) when using a filter in a view

Tags: 8, views

Here is a node structure which is storing cooking recipes

**recipe** (node)

-title (string)

-field_ingredient_quantity (paragraph) => see below the definition

-... (other fields)

**field_ingredient_quantity** (paragraph)

-field_ingredient (taxonomy term)

-field_quantity (float)

Let say that I woul like to filter in a view all recipes containing mustard with the [autocomplete filter](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_autocomplete_filters) on field_ingredient (inside the paragraph type field_ingredient_quantity)

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Why not try to define a relationship towards the `field_ingredient_quantity` and then add the `field_ingredient` in the fields of the view(should be available after defining the paragraph relationship). Afterwards just add the exposed filter with the autocomplete functionality.